# No partitions found c# cosmos

Tags: c#

Хотел создать FAT ( Файловую систему ) на c# с помощью cosmos.В интернете нашел код :

[image: Вот код]

Вставил как написано в before run но при запуске на виртуальной машине VMWare ошибка :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кто ни будь знает в чем причина?

Comment: Код надо вставлять текстом

Comment: https://github.com/CosmosOS/Cosmos/blob/master/Tests/Cosmos.System.Tests/DiskManagerTest.cs быть может это сойдет за пример

Comment: https://github.com/CosmosOS/Cosmos/blob/master/Tests/Cosmos.System.Tests/DiskManagerTest.cs - там вообще не находит библиотеку using Cosmos.System_Plugs.System.IO;